# UnboundLocalError issue using Python Dropbox API

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am trying to create a class in python which reads the access key/secret for dropbox and then downloads a file.  The key/secret part is working alright, but I seem to be having a problem recognizing the client object, probably due to an issue with global vs local variables.  I can't find my answer anywhere else.

Here's part of my code:

```
from dropbox import client, rest, session

class GetFile(object):

    def __init__(self, file1):
        self.auth_user()

    def auth_user(self):
        APP_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'
        TOKENS = 'dropbox_token.txt'

        token_file = open(TOKENS)
        token_key,token_secret = token_file.read().split('|')
        token_file.close()

        sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
        sess.set_token(token_key,token_secret)
        client = client.DropboxClient(sess)

        base, ext = file1.split('.')

        f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata(file1)
        out = open('/%s_COPY.%s' %(base, ext), 'w')
        out.write(f.read())
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "access_db.py", line 30, in <module>
start = GetFile(file_name)
File "access_db.py", line 6, in __init__
self.auth_user()
File "access_db.py", line 20, in auth_user
client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'client' referenced before assignment
```

I'm new-ish to python so let me know if there are other obvious things I may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You imported the `dropbox.client` module into a your module scope as `client`, but you *also* have a local variable `client` in your `.auth_user()` method.

When python sees an assignment (such as `client =`) in a function when compiling, it marks that name as a local variable. At this point your import of the `client` *module* is doomed, it is no longer visible in your function under that name.

Next, in python's eyes you are trying to access that local variable `client` in the function; you are trying to get the attribute `DropboxClient` from it, but you haven't yet assigned anything *to* the variable `client` at that moment. So the `UnboundLocal` exception is thrown.

The workaround is to either not use `client` as a local variable, to import the top-level `dropbox` module instead of it's submodules, then refer to it's submodules with the full `dropbox.client`, etc. paths, or thirdly, by giving the `client` module a new name:

1. Don't use `client` as a local:

   ```
   dbclient = client.DropboxClient(sess)
   # ...
   f, metadata = dbclient.get_file_and_metadata(file1)
   ```
2. Import the `dropbox` module directly:

   ```
   import dropbox
   # ...

       sess = dropbox.session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
       # ...
       client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(sess)
   ```
3. Provide an alias for the `client` module:

   ```
   from dropbox import session, rest
   from dropbox import client as dbclient
   # ...

       client = dbclient.DropboxClient(sess)
   ```